# How do i check in java for variable size?

Tags: java, android

Getting error on the return line and also not sure if the checking for the size is right.

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr = urlIn;
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);
            byte[] bufOut;

            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                if (szRead > 0) {
                    bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
                }
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

The part:

```
if (szRead > 0) {
                        bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
                    }
```

Not sure if this is the right way to check it in java and also when doing this i'm getting error on the variable bufOut might not be init in this line:

```
return bufOut;
```

Comment: you should initialize local variable before using them!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try returning the value returned by `Arrays.copyOf()` rather than store it in a variable  and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the possibly not initialised error because if `szRead` is zero or less, `bufOut` is not initialised. According to [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(byte[],%20int)), if `szRead` is negative (for example, if the file is at EOF when calling `read()`), it will throw an exception, so you could do either:

```
if (szRead==10*1024)
{
    throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
}
else
{
    bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
}
return bufOut;
```

And catch the `NegativeArraySizeException`, or throw another `AndroidRuntimeException` for szRead < 0, or just do:

```
bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead < 0 ? 0 : szRead);
```